# How do I create an individual nuget package for each project in a solution, with project references converted to nuget dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a solution that looks like this.

[image]

I would like to generate separate nuget packages for ProjA, ProjB and ProjC, and I would like this process to detect the project references shown above in ProjC, and convert them to nuget dependencies in the nuspec file, rather than just including the dlls for ProjA and ProjB in the ProjC nuget package, which is what happens at the moment when I use the 'nuget pack' command with the -IncludeReferencedProjects option.

This option says something about automatically either including the files or adding them as a dependency, but always includes them, even though I would like them added as a dependency.  Weirdly, in my realword solution, one of the project references always gets added as a dependency, but the rest don't and I can't figure out the difference.

How do I tell nuget to add them as a dependency?

I want the references to be project references as it makes it easier for development, rather than having to generate an update local nuget packages every time I want to test.

Comment: change project to "sdk style" (fx by creating new .net core project and TargetFramework to net48)

Comment: See description of IncludeReferencedProjects: `If a referenced project has a corresponding .nuspec file that has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is added as a dependency. Otherwise, the referenced project is added as part of the package`.

Comment: So only when we add `ProjA.nuspec` and `ProjB.nuspec` in corresponding project folder can `nuget pack` command recognize `ProjA` and `ProjB` as nuget packages. In this situation, `IncludeReferencedProjects` will take effect to add them as nuget dependencies as you expected... Apart from this, we can also choose to create a ProjC.nuspec and manually define the nuget dependencies there.

Comment: Just checking in to see if this issue is resolved, feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But always includes them, even though I would like them added as a
>   dependency. How do I tell nuget to add them as a dependency?

Assuming you're using `nuget pack` command instead of `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:pack`.

For `nuget pack xx.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects` command, to make sure the referenced projects are contained in your `ProjC` package with `nuget dependency` format, you should **add corresponding `xx.nuspec` file in referenced projects's folder**.

See the description of `IncludeReferencedProjects` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack#options):  If a referenced project has a corresponding `.nuspec` file that has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is **added as a dependency**. Otherwise, the referenced project is **added as part of the package**.

**So here's the workaround:**

1.For me, I open `cmd.exe` and navigate to ProjA's or ProjB's project folder, use `nuget sepc` command to create a `ProjectName.nuspec` for me in project folder.

2.Change the content of the `ProjA.nuspec` to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>ProjA</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>This is title.</title>
    <authors>This is author.</authors>
    <owners>These are owners.</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>This is description.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Now navigate to ProjC's folder and pack the ProjC again, the `IncludeReferencedProjects` will work as you expected. To check this: Rename the `ProjC.nupkg` to `ProjC.zip`, and check the content of generated `ProjC.nuspec` file in `ProjC.zip` file. You'll see something like `<dependency id="ProjA" version="1.0.0" />`.

**In addition**:

1.Since you're using `nuget pack` command and your projects target `.net framework`, I suggest you use `packages.config` format to manage nuget packages for the three projects.

2.To make your ProjC adds the ProjA and ProjB as nuget dependencies: Apart from using `IncludeReferencedProjects+ProjA.nuspec+ProjB.nuspec` way, actually we can simply create a `ProjC.nuspec` file and add content like below to manually define the dependencies.

```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="ProjA" version="1.0.0" />
      <dependency id="ProjB" version="1.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
```

Comment: It seems like the `dotnet pack` command has this behaviour by default, even without having to create nuspec files!