# Correct way to set up .net5 library projects with project dependencies in dev, but separate nuget packages when published

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-5, class-library

Suppose I am building two class libraries in a single solution in visual stuido. The projects are  called "Core" and "Extensions".

Extensions depends upon Core.

I would like to publish these as separate nuget packages for other developers to consume, because while the Core package would always be used, the extensions package just provides some optional functionality.

When I am developing the solution in visual studio, however, it is much simpler for me to set a project dependency from Extension to Core. Otherwise (in a naive approach), building the whole solution would require the following steps:

1. In visual studio, commit and push Core.
2. Wait for the CI server to build Core and publish the nuget package to our internal feed.
3. In visual studio, manage nuget packages for the Extensions project.
4. Connect to the internal nuget feed
5. Get the updated Core nuget package.

This approach would work, but is obviously very tedious.

The main difficulty I have been encountering while researching how to do this is that the way all of these things interact has been changing quite rapidly over the past few years, with sdk vs non sdk style projects, nuget pack vs dotnet pack vs msbuild pack, and so on and so forth.

Perhaps the most relevant, most recent answer appears in this question [How do I create an individual nuget package for each project in a solution, with project references converted to nuget dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150278/how-do-i-create-an-individual-nuget-package-for-each-project-in-a-solution-with) however the answer is now quite old, and is for a dot net framework style project (using packages.config), not a .net5 project.

So, can anyone provide up to date advice on how to correctly accomplish the following:

In a visual studio solution with multiple .net5 class library projects, have dependencies set up as project dependencies at dev-time, but convert each project to its own nuget package with the equivalent package dependencies at publish time.

Comment: You can have a try that workaround, the nuget command can work with .NET5.